# Cannot View JBOSS 6 using IP address:port on browser after starting Jboss on HP-ux

Tags: browser, port, ip-address, jboss6.x, hp-ux

I unzipped Jboss application server 6 on hp-ux connecting remotely and started the application server using sh run.sh and it started without error in both the buildup of the starting up as well as in the server.log.

But unfortunately, I cannot view the started application server in the browser using: e.g.

192,168.15.10:8080.

Anyone out there who can help?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

By default Jboss 6 binds its service to 127.0.0.1 only. You will need add "-b 0.0.0.0" to the startup script, something like run.bat -b 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're starting JBossAS using the `jboss-as-standalone.sh` script.

I recently had the same problem. JBoss assumes that accessing the server admin console from other machine is dangerous, so it's bindings are set by default to localhost or 127.0.0.1 at `/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.

Change the 3 `interfaces` elements to 0.0.0.0 so it can listen requests from all interfaces.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

It should work the same way if you're not running JBoss in standalone mode, so edit the `/domain/configuration/domain.xml` file.